# Copy dynamic ranges and append from one sheet to another

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have 3 data sheets all with the same headers (columns).  I need to copy all the data into one sheet.  The number of rows will vary for each data sheet each time I run the reports. The number of columns are always constant.  How do I copy data from sheet 2 and sheet 3 and append onto sheet 1?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have three sheets named Sheet 1:3, with data in A to C.

```
Sub combine_Sheets()

'Declare variables
Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim sht2 As Worksheet
Dim sht3 As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long

'Set variables
Set sht1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set sht2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
Set sht3 = Sheets("Sheet3")

'Copy Sheet 2 to Sheet 1

'Find Last row on Sheet 1
lastRow = Cells(sht1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Copy Sheet 2 data to bottom of Sheet 1
sht2.Range("A2:C" & Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Copy _
    Destination:=sht1.Range("A" & lastRow + 1)

'Copy Sheet 3 to Sheet 1

'Find new Last row on Sheet 1
lastRow = Cells(sht1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Copy Sheet 3 data to bottom of Sheet 1
sht3.Range("A2:C" & Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Copy _
    Destination:=sht1.Range("A" & lastRow + 1)

sht1.Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: Dear Sean, I used your code as well and it works perfectly when run manually, but when I run it from another sheet using a macro button, it messes everything up, only the header row gets copied and nothing else, what do you recommend?